# How to create a stream and sink for List of objects using BLOC

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, bloc

I have a list of objects as:

```
[{name: "Rob", age: 20}, {name: "Bob", age: 30},]
```

How can I create a stream and sink for this?

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find any solution.

I know for a String or double or any other datatype, like this:

```
  final _name = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  Stream<String> get name => _name.stream;

  Function(String) get changeName => _name.sink.add;
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Going by your sample code, you can have a stream and sink for the List of Maps like below:

```
final _personList = BehaviorSubject<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>();

Stream<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> get name => _name.stream;

Function(List<Map<String, dynamic>>) get changeName => _name.sink.add;
```

Comment: But how can I add name and age index wise?

Comment: You can sort your list before adding the items to the sink.